# How to validate following in picklists in apex salesforce?

Tags: validation, time, salesforce, apex-code, picklist

I'm just starting with salesforce and using picklists in following way:
see img:
[image]

See, I have four picklists. I want to validate when From Time and To Time is AM and AM; I want to do : **To time should not be grater than from time**
I am not able to validate it. I'm trying to solve it with validations nad apex code but I don't know what's going wrong.
please provide some insights, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your four picklist fields are FromTime, FromAMPM, ToTime, ToAMPM, the "Error Condition Formula" for the Validation Rule should be:

```
TEXT(FromAMPM__c) == TEXT(ToAMPM__c) &&
VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(FromTime__c),LEN(TEXT(FromTime__c))-3)) >
VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(ToTime__c), LEN(TEXT(ToTime__c))-3))
```

If the user picks (AM, AM) or (PM, PM), we convert the text before ":00" (the last 3 characters) to numbers and compare them.

- TEXT() converts a picklist value into a text: [TEXT()](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm)
- VALUE() converts a text string to a number: [VALUE()](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VALUE)